# What’s a catchy phrase that means get the most out of your dollar?

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests, expression-choice

I’m trying to finish a speech, and I was thinking of a catchy last idiom to wrap it up. It was on the tip of my tongue and it I think it mean get the most out of your dollar or something like that....

“So next time you hold a dollar in your hand remind yourself , ___(PHRASE______.”

Comment: Voting to close because writing ad copy isn't our line of work here.

Answer (score 4):

The idiom that immediately comes to my mind is **bang for your buck**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang_for_the_buck):

> **Bang for the buck** is an idiom meaning the worth of one's money or exertion. The phrase originated from the slang usage of the words "bang" which means "excitement" and "buck" which means "money".[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang_for_the_buck) Variations of the term include "bang for **your** buck," "bang for **one's** buck," "**more** bang for the buck," "**bigger** bang for the buck," and mixings of these. "More bang for the buck" was preceded by "more bounce to the ounce", an advertising slogan used in 1950 to market the carbonated soft drink Pepsi.

In your example sentence, you might say:

> So next time you hold a dollar in your hand, remind yourself to get *the most bang for your buck*.

Comment: little typo there at the end.... *ban**k** for your buck*?

Comment: @Hellion Ha! Fixed. I'm not sure what Freud would have said.

Comment: Thank you show much guys. Y’all are hw lifesavers

Comment: @JasonBassford - You can take that one to the bang!

Answer (score 1):

Thrifty, according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thrifty):

> given to or marked by economy and good management